# Swift - Could not find an overload for '=='

Tags: swift, overloading

```
func fibonnaci(n: Int) {
    return n == 0 || n == 1 ? n : fibonnaci(n - 1) + fibonnaci(n - 2)
}
```

I am on Xcode 6.4 and I get the error message `Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments`. I've seen other related problems, but they involve the types being strings or floats, etc. These are all ints! I don't understand...

Comment: Your function should declare its return type since it returns something.

Comment: *Tip:* If you don't understand an error message, *simplify* the problem first. If you simplify your function body to `return 0` then you'll get the very clear error message "error: unexpected non-void return value in void function".

Comment: bonus: fibonacci has one `n` and two `c`s

Comment: @MartinR the problem is that this error message is actually not helpful/misleading/irrelevant (not unlike other Swift error messages!). Poor `==` operator has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Sure. That's why I suggested to simplify/reduce the code to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't declare which type the function returns. This will work:

```
func fibonnaci(n: Int) -> Int {
   return n == 0 || n == 1 ? n : fibonnaci(n - 1) + fibonnaci(n - 2)
}
```